# FloatingActionButton doesn't show icon inside of?

Tags: kotlin, material-ui, material-design, floating-action-button

I have tried to use FAB button for add new somethings in my android application, but FAB have not showed its source icon. can you help me how i resolve it?

this is my main_activity.xml:

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:id="@+id/main_container">
    
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/frg_holder"/>
    
                <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:elevation="6dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"/>
    
            </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is a ic_add.xml create icon inside of fAB:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/>
</vector>
```

and this is gradle :

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.samanzamani.persiandate:PersianDate:0.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Did you try a normal png to check if everything is good?

Comment: yes i did but i have same problem